# Multiple hostnames on a single machine with IIS and self-hosted WCF

Tags: wcf, iis, binding

I have two hostnames, a domain and subdomain (`example.com` and `service.example.com`) both pointing to a single (Windows 2008) server. The server is running IIS 7 (hosting an ASP.NET web site) and a self-hosted WCF service. I want IIS to handle requests to `http://example.com` and the WCF service to handle requests to `http://service.example.com`.

The problem is that if the service is running, it "intercepts" all HTTP requests regardless of the Host header. In other words, if I visit `http://example.com` in a web browser, I get the WCF "You have created a service" page instead of the ASP.NET site. If the service is not running, IIS handles the requests as expected.

The IIS site has a single HTTP binding on port 80, with the `example.com` hostname specified.

The relevant portion of the service's app.config file is as follows. I have tried all three `hostNameComparisonMode` values with no luck.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttp" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ExampleServiceBehavior" name="Example.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttp" contract="Example.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://service.example.com/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Are you on Windows Vista/7 or 2008 server? ... If not you might have a hard time unless you can bind a second IP address.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, running IIS 7. I've updated the question to reflect this point. You're right that this would be difficult if not impossible without kernel-level HTTP support.

Comment: Nope, never did. I just gave up on using the subdomain and used URL paths instead (`example.com` and `example.com/service`). It will be difficult in the future if I need to move the service to a different physical server and maintain my URL structure, but what I have works for now, and I needed to move on.